# Need to display result of addition in a text box using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function

I need to create two text boxes where the user can insert number, and a button that adds them.

I need to use the .val() to bring the data from the html body, that is done.

My issue  is that I don't know how to display the result in a text box, and not using the alert option.

Help!

Comment: can you provide the code you're working on?

Comment: what have you tried? - posts should include some code you have tried, and possible errors if you have any

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and revise your question.

Comment: Did you get it to work using the fiddle?

Answer (score 2):

You need to add change listeners to your html elements and you need to run a function on change.

```
<input type='number' id='firstBox' onChange='calculate()' />
<input type='number' id='secondBox' onChange='calculate()' />

<input type='number' id='answerBox' />
```

```js
function calculate(){
    var first = Number(document.getElementById('firstBox').value)
    var second = Number(document.getElementById('secondBox').value)

    var answer = document.getElementById('answer')
    answer.value = first + second
}
```

Also, I created a quick fiddle for you [here](https://jsfiddle.net/4Pxqg/2/), definitely check it out it will help you get acquainted.